# Subtract a value from every number more than 250 using the if statement in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, math

This the code that I've been using, but it doesn't work.

```
x=[448.45009861025136,407.926398673343,370.37041013518717,110.80024496401921,
 132.763253167909,290.71258650497805,343.445508200621,90.32213589961538,275.6475130629087,
 286.5755699930108,270.1987754529232,285.9797633022938,125.70236429739884,392.1611941440351,
 123.20295634613336,333.62671024414226]

for j in x:
    if j>360.0:
        x=j-360.0

    else:
        j=j
```

Comment: I think you meant `j=j-360.0`, not `x=j-360.0`

Comment: Is `j=j` doing anything meaningful?

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension:

```
x =[448.45009861025136,407.926398673343,370.37041013518717,110.80024496401921,132.763253167909,290.71258650497805,343.445508200621,90.32213589961538,275.6475130629087,286.5755699930108,270.1987754529232,285.9797633022938,125.70236429739884,392.1611941440351,123.20295634613336,333.62671024414226]
output = [i - 360 if i > 360 else i for i in x]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
[88.45009861025136, 47.92639867334299, 10.370410135187171, 110.80024496401921,
 132.763253167909, 290.71258650497805, 343.445508200621, 90.32213589961538,
 275.6475130629087, 286.5755699930108, 270.1987754529232, 285.9797633022938,
 125.70236429739884, 32.16119414403511, 123.20295634613336, 333.62671024414226]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for index,j in enumerate(x):
    if j>360.0:
        x[index]=j-360.0
```

You cannot replace a value in a list by assigning the value to the whole list. I fixed it by using an index. Btw you don't need that else statement.

Answer (score 1):

another syntax to do this with lambda:

```
result = list(map(lambda value: value < 360 and value or value - 360, x))
```

result variable with your data will be:

```
[88.45009861025136, 47.92639867334299, 10.370410135187171, 110.80024496401921, 132.763253167909, 290.71258650497805, 343.445508200621, 90.32213589961538, 275.6475130629087, 286.5755699930108, 270.1987754529232, 285.9797633022938, 125.70236429739884, 32.16119414403511, 123.20295634613336, 333.62671024414226]
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, because `j` is not a pointer to the list value, because the list values are not objects. So you need something different like:

```
x = [448.45009861025136,407.926398673343,370.37041013518717,110.80024496401921, 132.763253167909,290.71258650497805,343.445508200621,90.32213589961538,275.6475130629087, 286.5755699930108,270.1987754529232,285.9797633022938,125.70236429739884,392.1611941440351, 123.20295634613336,333.62671024414226]

x = [j if j < 360 else j - 360 for j in x]
```

Comment: What is this syntax?

Comment: This is called "list comprehension", see e.g. https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python.

Comment: I'm talking about your Java syntax inside Python code.

Comment: It is call the "InvalidSyntax". Python does not have this syntax for the ternary operator.

Comment: Dear, you are using ternary operator syntax which is different in Python. Python does not have `?:` syntax.

Comment: Ah, sorry, have been doing Typescript past days, so mixed it up :-) Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension and subtract 360 or zero to every element.

like this:

```
x = [ j-360*(j>360) for j in x ]
```